# Mean and Variance of Exponential Distribution

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, exponential-distribution

Show that the exponential distribution $f_X(x) = y_0\cdot\exp\left(\frac{-x}{\sigma}\right)$, mean and variance are equal.

My attempt:

The value of the mean that I got is y0.σ² which is not equal to the variance.
Can you please help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Here they didn't give you the normalization constant (what they called $y_0$), so you need to go through and find it.

Comment: @Ian : I think also X domain is missing...

Comment: @tommik Technically yes but it's being called the exponential distribution so it's presumably $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @Ian : mmmhh... It looks like the OP has to find a "truncated" exponential so that mean= variance...thus probably also X domain is unknown...or simply $\sigma=1$

Comment: @tommik Oh, I got mixed up between variance and standard deviation; the normal exponential distribution has the same mean and standard deviation.

Comment: @Ian: ahah...maybe you are right. There can be a typo in the question: "show that mean and st dev" are the same...let's wait OP comments

Comment: The question here says mean and variance are equal. And 0 ≤ x < ∞. σ > 0

Comment: @Learner: so stated, the question is wrong, because $y_0=1/\sigma$ and, as you know mean cannot be equal to variance unless you set $\sigma=1$